# Spring poller roll back on exception after a particular retry count

Tags: spring, spring-integration, rollback

My poller fetches data from DB and pass it to a service activator.
If any exception happens in the service activator method,i should roll back the data fetched to its previous state and  should again send the same data to the service activater only for a specific retry-count(say 3)**. **Is it possible to do this in a xml configuration**. ? For details i will share the poller configurations and the service activator.
**poller.xml**

```html
 <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="datachannel"
  query="select loyalty_id,process_id,mobile_uid from TBL_RECEIPT where r_cre_time
  =(select min(r_cre_time) from TBL_RECEIPT where receipt_status=0)"
  data-source="dataSource" max-rows-per-poll="1"
  update="update TBL_RECEIPT set receipt_status=11 where process_id in (:process_id)">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
  <int:transactional/>
  </int:poller>
 </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>


<int:channel id="errors">
<int:queue/>
</int:channel>

   <bean id="poller" class="main.java.com.as.poller.PollerService" />

 <int:channel id="executerchannel">
  <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" />
 </int:channel> 


 <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2" />

 <int:service-activator input-channel="datachannel"
  output-channel="executerchannel" ref="poller" method="getRecordFromPoller">
   <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
  <int:retry-advice recovery-channel="errors" />
  </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
 </int:service-activator>
 

     <int:service-activator input-channel="executerchannel"
  ref="poller" method="getDataFromExecuterChannel">
 </int:service-activator>
```

**service activator method**

```html
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })

 @ServiceActivator

 public void processMessage(Message message) throws IOException {
  int capLimit = Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("capping_limit"));
  
  List<Map<String, Object>> rows = (List<Map<String, Object>>) message
    .getPayload();
  for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
   String loyaltyId = (String) row.get("loyalty_id");
   String processId = (String) row.get("process_id");
   String xid=(String)row.get("mobile_uid");
```

i have heard about int:transactional being used in poller configuration.But when i added it,its taking the same record even after successful transaction.(means its getting rolled back everytime).
Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to execute the same stuff knowing it's going to fail?

Comment: from the service activater i am calling an external system.If i get any exception from that service,i need to roll back the transaction and do retries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [retry request-handler-advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to the service activator.

To make retry stateful (throw the exception so the transaction will rollback) you need to provide a `RetryStateGenerator`. Otherwise the thread will simply be suspended during the retries.

Regardless of using stateful or stateless retry, you really should use a transactional poller so that the update is only applied after success.

> means its getting rolled back everytime

The transactional poller will only rollback if an exception is thrown. So if you're seeing the same row, something must be failing.

Turn on DEBUG logging for all of `org.springframework` to follow the message flow and transaction activity.

Comment: I will try this and let you know.Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: From the link that you provided http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain ...
The retry advice (o.s.i.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice) leverages the rich retry mechanisms .I am unable to find this class.jetty server is throwing error.I know i am stupid to ask this,but i have no idea.should i create a class called RequestHandlerRetryAdvice on myself.?if so what should i write in that class.?can you please clarify?

Comment: `o.s.i.` is an abbreviation - see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/_conventions_in_this_book.html). The class is in `spring-integration-core` and was introduced in version 2.2; the current version is 4.2.2.

Comment: so i should replace o.s.i with the real name ?I am using spring version 4.1.6

Comment: Yes; if you use an IDE (such as IDEA or eclipse/STS) you should be able to just type the Simple classname and the IDE will auto-fill the rest.

Comment: If you scroll down to `Namespace Support for Stateless Retry` in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#advice-classes) you can see that you don't even need the class name since 4.0.

Comment: Hi gary, I am faced with a situation here.Retry is working fine as you said.But after 3 retries,poller is taking the same record from DB.Is there anyway to stop the poller after 3 retries if no next record exists or just take the next record?can you please help ?

Comment: Use stateless retry, or a transactional poller.

Comment: i edited the poller.xml...used a stateless retry and added an update query.Now retry is not happening..after 1st exception query is getting updated ...:(

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` and examine the logs for message flow/retry etc. If you still can't figure it out, post the log someplace like pastebin or github gist (too big for here).

Comment: after a run time exception happening in the datachannel...poller is doing the the update query.hence retry is not happening...is there any solution for this ?can you please suggest any idea..?

Comment: You need to use a transactional poller to rollback the update - the update is done before the flow is invoked.

Comment: Gary rusel please try to understand the situation..please..after 3 unsuccessful retries,poller is again taking the same record.It means update is not happening.I have tried what all u said to me..but still none of it is working.If u have time for atleast 5 minutes to look into this i know u can tell it...This full day i am behind this..

Comment: Sorry. I don't have time to write a test case for every question asked here. If you post a complete test case that reproduces your issue, I will take a look at it.

Comment: test case is : poller fetches one record->gives to service activator->throws run time exception from service activator->3 unsuccessful retries are done->again the poller fetches the same ->leading to infinite loop.I would like do an update query after 3 unsuccessful retries so that poller can take 2nd record.If u want anything else sir,please tell me.

Comment: I said __".. post a complete test case that reproduces your issue, I will take a look at it"__. All you have done is __describe__ the test case. I am not going to write the code/config for you. If I write it, it will work. You need to post the project somewhere (e.g. github) that doesn't work using the help I've given you. It will take me much, much, less time to tell you what's wrong with your test than for me to write one for you that works.

Comment: why are you so rude to me sir ?i did anything wrong ?i dont want you to write a code /config for me..i was just expecting an answer from you like "hey man, just add that thing in adapter or something,then it will work".I am running out of time so writing test case and commiting in git is hard for me as of now.

Comment: I am not being rude; in order to prove to you that it works, I would need to write a test case; I have explained all the details to you but we're obviously having a communication problem - either you don't understand me, or I don't understand your problem. The easiest way to solve that is for you to provide a concrete test that I can run so I can more clearly understand what your problem is.

Comment: I broke down and patched the [jdbc sample](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/6968edb71c32e318324eb4a74421cd173b8f1bb4?w=1) to show it works exactly as I described.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..It is working now perfectly.The mistake was i didn't added an error channel and subcribed it the 'recovery-channel' field in the retry advice...God bless you..